# How to ensure that system-userdbd.service is started after root fs became writeable without creating circular dependencies?

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

I have a fast virtual machine and the systemd service `systemd-zserdbd.service` fails with

```
Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new systemd[1]: Starting systemd-remount-fs.service...

...

Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new (-userdbd)[183]: systemd-userdbd.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-userdbd: Read-only file system
Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new (-userdbd)[185]: systemd-userdbd.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-userdbd: Read-only file system
Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new systemd[1]: Started systemd-journald.service.
Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new (-userdbd)[186]: systemd-userdbd.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-userdbd: Read-only file system
Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new (-userdbd)[187]: systemd-userdbd.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-userdbd: Read-only file system
Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new (-userdbd)[188]: systemd-userdbd.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-userdbd: Read-only file system

...

Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new systemd-fsck[180]: /usr/bin/fsck.xfs: XFS file system.
Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new systemd[1]: Finished systemd-remount-fs.service.

...

Dec 01 17:45:32 server-new systemd[1]: Reached target local-fs-pre.target.

...

Dec 01 17:45:33 server-new systemd[1]: Reached target local-fs.target.
```

The error is quite obvious: `systemd-userdbd.service` requires a writable root file system, but is started before the file system is re-mounted as writable.

Hence, I wanted to add the necessary dependency via `systemctl edit systemd-userdbd.service --drop-in=wait-for-rw-root` with

```
[Unit]
Wants=local-fs.target
After=systemd-userdbd.socket systemd-remount-fs.service local-fs.target
```

But this seems to create a circular dependency at boot time. Re-mounting the file systems takes forever until systemd runs into a timeout.

1. How do I ensure that `systemd-userdbd.service` is started after the the root file system has become writable without creating a circular dependency?
2. (A more general question) How do I analyze what creates the circular dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself. `systemd-userdbd.socket` triggers `systemd-userdbd.service`. Hence, the solution was to put the additional dependencies into `systemd-userdbd.socket` which delays the socket from coming up and in turn also delays the corresponding service.

I created a drop-in via `systemctl edit systemd-userdbd.socket --drop-in=wait-for-rw-root` with the following content

```
[Unit]
After=systemd-remount-fs.service local-fs.target
Wants=local-fs.target
```

But basically it is an upstream bug as the service requires a writable root fs but fails to add that to its requisites.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that systemd-userdbd.service is started after the the root file system has become writable without creating a circular dependency?

Have your initramfs (or the kernel) mount the file system as read-write immediately, without going through the "ro-fsck-remount-rw" dance. That is, boot with the `rw` kernel option instead of `ro`.

(There would usually be the first step of making sure your initramfs has 'fsck' included in it, but in your case 'fsck.xfs' does literally nothing else except for printing the message, so you'll do fine without it.)

> (A more general question) How do I analyze what creates the circular dependency?

`systemctl list-dependencies --after` should show it.

Systemd will print out each component of an ordering loop into the journal. Log in as root and check `journalctl -b` for "`deleted to break ordering cycle`".

Comment: I wouldn't call this an answer. Mounting the root writable and hence skipping the possibility to have a file system check if necessary, is a bad work-around.

Comment: @user2690527: No, mounting the root filesystem read-only before doing the check is a bad work-around for not having your initramfs fsck it before mounting (and then possibly altering it while it's mounted...) Fedora's Dracut, Debian's update-initramfs, and Arch's mkinitcpio can all include fsck in the initramfs (and some even do so by default); your distribution should be able to do the same.

Comment: There are setups which do not even use an initramfs.

Comment: Exactly my point; ro-remount is a workaround that's needed for such setups.